# Ajax rating control not working on mouse over

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

Ajax rating control is not working on mouse over.
I have mentioned classes for waiting, filled, empty states. 
But its not changing the css class on mouse over.
I dont know what is missing.

This is css.

```
.ratingStar 
    {
        font-size: 0pt;
        width: 15px;
        height: 18px;
        display: block;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
.filledRatingStar
        {
            background-image:url('images/star_full.png');
        }
 .emptyRatingStar
        {
            background-image:url('images/star_empty.png');
        }
 .savedRatingStar
        {
            background-color:red;
        }
```

And Here is the body,

```
<div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <ajaxToolkit:Rating ID="ThaiRating" runat="server" BehaviorID="RatingBehavior1"
                    CurrentRating="0"
                    MaxRating="5"
                    StarCssClass="ratingStar"
                    WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar"
                   FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar"
                    EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar"
                    style="float: left;" />
    </div>
```

And I have registered the assembly on top as,

```
<%@ Register
    Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
    TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

Please anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

replace :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

with this Ajax Control:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server"  ID="ScriptManager1" />
```

and it will work fine ;)